# AWK using file to remove csv rows

Tags: csv, awk

I have the following csv:

old.csv

```
irrelevant,irrelevant,Abc@gmail.com,irrelevant
irrelevant,irrelevant,zyx@gmail.com,irrelevant
irrelevant,irrelevant,yZ@yahoo.com,irrelevant
irrelevant,irrelevant,that@email.com,irrelevant
irrelevant,irrelevant,this@email.com,irrelevant
irrelevant,irrelevant,def@gmail.com,irrelevant
irrelevant,irrelevant,anoTher@mydomain.com,irrelevant
```

that I need to remove the rows containing emails from this file:

remove.txt

```
abc@gmail.com
yz@yahoo.com
this@email.com
another@mydomain.com
```

And I need the output to be this:

new.csv

```
irrelevant,irrelevant,zyx@gmail.com,irrelevant
irrelevant,irrelevant,that@email.com,irrelevant
irrelevant,irrelevant,def@gmail.com,irrelevant
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work.  Can anyone help?

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1};NR==FNR{remove[$1]++;next}!($1 in remove)' remove.txt old.csv > new.csv
```

Comment: can you try changing `($1 in remove)` into `($3 in remove)` ? In fact you can do `!remove[$3]`. If you have case problem, there is `toupper/lower()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. IGNORECASE is gawk-specific, you may not be using gawk.
2. You're testing the wrong field.
3. Incrementing the array element does nothing useful.

Try this:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{remove[tolower($1)];next}!(tolower($3) in remove)' remove.txt old.csv > new.csv
```

Comment: This works right out the box!  Thanks for the solution my friend!

Answer (score 2):

With `grep`:

```
grep -v -i -f remove.txt all.csv
```

Here,

- `-f` - Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.
- `-i` - Ignore case
- `-v` - Invert the matching

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} {for(var in a){if($3 ~ var){print}}}' remove.txt all.csv
```

Another `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[tolower($1)]++;next} !(tolower($3) in a){print}' remove.txt all.csv
```

In your case, it won't work. Because,

```
IGNORECASE=1
```

will work only on `if (x ~ /ab/)` and not with array indexes.

```
index in array
```

Comment: The grep command would need a lot of work to be reliable. As-is it'll find an email address in the wrong field, it'll match "able@foo.com" with "capable@foo.com", it'll match "able@foo.com" with "able@foolcom.net", etc.... When you need to match on a field, just use awk.

Comment: @sat The grep is not good for very large lists.  It caused some sort of giganitic memory consumption.  Also, your 1st AWK doesn't work, but the 2nd one does.  Thanks for the 2nd one!